# How to remove part of each string-element in a list in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, edit

I have a long list of dates in the form ["2019-11-01 00:15:00+01", "2019-11-01 00:30:00+01", "2019-11-01 00:45:00+01" ... and so on] in the type of strings. I would like to go through the list and remove the "00:15:00+01"-part. I have tried with a dummy list first, but I cant seem to make it work. **How can I remove part of the string elements in a list?**

```
    url = ['abcdc.com', 'tzr.com']
    for i in range(0,len(url)):
       if url[i].endswith('.com'):
          url[i] = url[:-4]
```

The code above only returns: url = [[],[]]. Why?
Any help you be greatly appreciated!

Comment: url[i] = url[:-4] should be url[i] = url[i][:-4]

Answer (score 2):

you could use split as:

```
dates = ["2019-11-01 00:15:00+01", "2019-11-01 00:30:00+01", "2019-11-01 00:45:00+01"]
new_dates = []
for date in dates:
    new_dates.append(date.split()[0])
```

print(new_dates)

```
['2019-11-01', '2019-11-01', '2019-11-01']
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, would this do?

```py
>>> url = ['abcdc.com', 'tzr.com']
>>> url = [x[:-4] if x.endswith('.com') else x for x in url]
>>> url
['abcdc', 'tzr']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to extract only dates.

```
import re
x = [re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', l).group(0) for l in li ]
```

---

**x:**

```
['2019-11-01', '2019-11-01', '2019-11-01']
```

Answer (score 1):

this can solve your problem:

```
url = ['abcdc.com', 'tzr.com']
for i in range(0, len(url)):
    if url[i].endswith('.com'):
        url[i] = url[i][:-4]
```

A better way to solve your problem is by using `split()` to separate each element in `data _time` list,
as so:

```
date_time_list =["2019-11-01 00:15:00+01", "2019-11-01 00:30:00+01", "2019-11-01 00:45:00+01"]
date_list = []

for elem in date_time_list:
     if elem is None:
         date_list.append(None)
         continue
     date,time = elem.split()
     date_list.append(date)
print(date_list)
>>> ['2019-11-01', '2019-11-01', '2019-11-01']
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! However, I realized I have a 'nan' in my list - and get this error message: "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)". Do you know how I could solve this without deleting the 'nan'?

Comment: for elem in date_time_list:
     if elem is None:
          date_list.append(None)
          continue
     date,time = elem.split()
     date_list.append(date)